# Interaction between the recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

there are two recyclerview and two adapters. Both recyclerview contain text fields and buttons. I have below pressing in one recyclerview item jumped to another recyclerview and vice versa. How to do it?

First adapter:

```
public class RVAdapterStart extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterStart.TaskViewHolder> {
public static class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private TextView title;
    private TextView status;
    private Button button;

    TaskViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.tasks_finish);
    }
}

private List<Task> tasksStart;

RVAdapterStart() {

}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.title.setText(tasksStart.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.status.setText(tasksStart.get(position).getStatus());
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasksStart.size();
}

@Override
public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_tasks_start, viewGroup, false);
    TaskViewHolder tvh = new TaskViewHolder(view);
    return tvh;
}
```

Second adapter:

```
public class RVAdapterProcces extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterProcces.TasksViewHolder> {
public static class TasksViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private TextView title;
    private TextView status;
    private Button TaskFinishBtn;
    private Button TaskCancelBtn;

    TasksViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative_tasks_procces);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_procces);
        status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status_procces);
        TaskFinishBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.tasks_finish);
        TaskCancelBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.tasks_procces_cancel);
    }
}

private List<Task> tasksProcces = new ArrayList<Task>();

RVAdapterProcces() {

}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TasksViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.title.setText(tasksProcces.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.status.setText(tasksProcces.get(position).getStatus());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasksProcces.size();
}

@Override
public TasksViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_tasks_procces, viewGroup, false);
    TasksViewHolder tvh = new TasksViewHolder(view);
    return tvh;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about animation ?

Comment: No, i do not understand how to organize this interaction.

Comment: Your question is not clear, if you are asking how to move it then you have to add an item in the second adapter and call notifiyDatasetChanged() method on second list, this will update the list and your newly added item will appear. Remove from the first list and notify to remove

Comment: @Jaive Can you please java post the java file in which you have **RecyclerView**?

Comment: Do you want to replace or copy or do some interactions of data of item in recyclerview1 to recyclerview2 ?

Comment: For each recyclerview is the list from which are taken the data and when you change, you need to call notifiyDatasetChanged() - I understand that. You need to by clicking on the item is removed from one list and added to another, but how to do it, if the lists are in different adapters. It would be logical to hang up listeners on the buttons in the activity, but how to get access to these buttons in activity, not in the adapter? Sorry for my bad English :)